# Access denied from website to database hosted in MS Azure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I got a simple website hosted on SmarterAsp.net.
The database is hosted on MS Azure.
When I try to log in the app and connect to the db, I got Access is denied error.

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Access is denied.)]

Yes, I allowed the website's IP address in the db's firewall settings.
The connection string on the website looks like this:

> Data Source=sasdb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=SaSDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX

I am not sure what else to check apart from the allowed IP addresses..
Thank you
Petr

EDIT:
Ok, so the site is http://speakasspeaker.info/ there is a test button on the main page called Test, when I click it, it should just return some row count from the database. I went to Azure, get a new connection string which looks like this:

> Server=tcp:sasdb.database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=sasdb.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=SaSDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;

Now I got new error

> The network path was not found

When you click the button it will show you the stack trace..
Thanks

Comment: Did you open the IP *and* the port? Is the DNS name visible from the outside? Are you able to telnet to that port, ie does `telnet sasdb.database.windows.net 1433` run or does it hang?

Comment: Hi, I dont have really full access to the hosting machine, it's just some hosting service I use. Do you mean ping it FROM the machine on the hosting service? How and where do I open the port?

Answer (score 0):

Soo, it works now, I had to upgrade my hosting plan and really had to allow access  to the db, it's IP address and port (1433) and it works now.